# Maximum of difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

If I have $y(n) = - \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \cdot y(n-k) + \sum_{k=0}^M b_k \cdot x(n-k)$
with

$|x(n)|\leq L\\ 
y(n-k) = 0 \text{ for all } n-k \lt 0 \\
x(n-k) = 0 \text{ for all } n-k \lt 0 \\
n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
k \in \mathbb{N} \\
a_{k} \text{ and } \ b_{k}  \text{ are constants }\in \mathbb{R}
$

How can I get the maximum $y(n)$ value of this difference equation? Can you suggest me some book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this generality, little can be said. Anything can happen. For example, $$y(n)=2y(n-1)+x(n-1)$$ is a particular instance of this problem. Suppose $x(n)=1$  for all $n\in\mathbb N$  (or even just for one), then $y$ grows exponentially, and there is no maximum at all.

To bring the problem into focus, you should  impose some conditions that will prevent $y$ from growing indefinitely. For example, $\sum_{k=1}^N |a_k|<1$.

Comment: Thanks, and if I have this condition, how can I do that?